# John wishes he (were/would be) richer

Tags: tense, subjunctives, exam-questions

> John wishes **he will be** richer.

The above sentence is a sentence correction question asked in my exam. I know the bold part is incorrect but I am not able to figure out how to correct it should I use *were* or should I go for *would be* ? Although *were* sounds more natural to me, I tried to google for *wish* usage and [here](http://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish) found both being used in different sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Both

> **1.** John wishes he were richer

and

> **2.** John wishes he would be richer

are correct.

However, they mean two different things. **1.** refers to the present and **2.** refers to the future.

If John's wish about being richer would have referred to the past, as in a regret, the sentence would have had to be written like this:

> **3.** John wishes he had been richer.

---

As to

> *John wishes he will be richer,

this sentence is not correct.